# magento 2 don't want to show proceed to checkout button based on custom condition

Tags: magento2, checkout, mini-cart

How to hide **Proceed to Checkout** button in the mini cart section magneto 2 from custom module based on my condition.

For example: 
                   if the custom session data is set then hide - Proceed To Checkout
                   if the custom session data is not set then show - Proceed To Checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `default.xml` file here in your module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <referenceBlock name="minicart">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/minicart/content</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now you need to create `content.html` file here on this path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

You can copy content of this default Vendor file there and comment button code

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

If you want to add condition in that button then you need to create one `requirejs-config.js` file here on this location in your custom module..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Content for this file is..

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/minicart-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now create one `minicart-mixin.js` file here on this location

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart-mixin.js

Content for this file is..

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, _) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        isButtonEnable: function () {
            /*You can add your condition here based on your requirements.*/
            return true;
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

- Here in this `JS` file I've added **isButtonEnable()** function there you can add your condition here based on your requirement to show hide your button.

And you can add condition in your `content.html` file like this

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

Content for this file is..

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="block-title">
    <strong>
        <span class="text" translate="'My Cart'"/>
        <span
            class="qty empty"
            text="getCartParam('summary_count')"
            data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false },
                       attr: { title: $t('Items in Cart') }">
        </span>
    </strong>
</div>

<div class="block-content">
    <button type="button"
            id="btn-minicart-close"
            class="action close"
            data-action="close"
            data-bind="attr: { title: $t('Close') }">
        <span translate="'Close'"/>
    </button>

    <if args="getCartParam('summary_count')">
        <div class="items-total">
            <span class="count" if="maxItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()" text="maxItemsToDisplay"/>
            <translate args="'of'" if="maxItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()"/>
            <span class="count" text="getCartParam('summary_count')"/>
                <!-- ko if: (getCartLineItemsCount() === 1) -->
                    <span translate="'Item in Cart'"/>
                <!--/ko-->
                <!-- ko if: (getCartLineItemsCount() > 1) -->
                    <span translate="'Items in Cart'"/>
                <!--/ko-->
        </div>

        <each args="getRegion('subtotalContainer')" render=""/>
        <each args="getRegion('extraInfo')" render=""/>

        <div class="actions" if="getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout')">
            <div class="primary">
                <if args="isButtonEnable()">
                    <button
                            id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
                            type="button"
                            class="action primary checkout"
                            data-action="close"
                            data-bind="
                                attr: {
                                    title: $t('Proceed to Checkout')
                                },
                                click: closeMinicart()
                            "
                            translate="'Proceed to Checkout'"
                    />
                </if>
                <div data-bind="html: getCartParam('extra_actions')"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </if>

    <if args="getCartParam('summary_count')">
        <strong class="subtitle" translate="'Recently added item(s)'"/>
        <div data-action="scroll" class="minicart-items-wrapper">
            <ol id="mini-cart" class="minicart-items" data-bind="foreach: { data: getCartItems(), as: 'item' }">
                <each args="$parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type))"
                      render="{name: getTemplate(), data: item, afterRender: function() {$parents[1].initSidebar()}}"
                />
            </ol>
        </div>
    </if>

    <ifnot args="getCartParam('summary_count')">
        <strong class="subtitle empty"
                data-bind="visible: closeSidebar()"
                translate="'You have no items in your shopping cart.'"
        />
        <if args="getCartParam('cart_empty_message')">
            <p class="minicart empty text" text="getCartParam('cart_empty_message')"/>
            <div class="actions">
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                        <span translate="'View and Edit Cart'"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </if>
    </ifnot>

    <div class="actions" if="getCartParam('summary_count')">
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                <span translate="'View and Edit Cart'"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="minicart-widgets" class="minicart-widgets" if="getRegion('promotion').length">
        <each args="getRegion('promotion')" render=""/>
    </div>
</div>
<each args="getRegion('sign-in-popup')" render=""/>
```

I've added condition in above file in button

```
<if args="isButtonEnable()">
    <button
            id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
            type="button"
            class="action primary checkout"
            data-action="close"
            data-bind="
                attr: {
                    title: $t('Proceed to Checkout')
                },
                click: closeMinicart()
            "
            translate="'Proceed to Checkout'"
    />
</if>
```

[image]

You can download this module as well [here](https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/show-hide-proceed-to-checkout-minicart)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will try and update you but one small query @krishan can u suggest how to keep conditions here for that button like if the session data is set...etc..

Comment: If customer is logged in then you want to show that button otherwise not ? Am I right here ?

Comment: we are storing some data in the session variable in our custom helper (custom module). if that value is set then -> hide mini cart button. If not set then show mini cart button.

Comment: Okay give me few mins I'll update my answer

Comment: Ok sure thanks for your support

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Comment: Give me 5 mints @krishan let me check and update you

Comment: Okay,  sure @NIPPU

Comment: Hi @kishan I have tried your solution but the content.phtml is still calling from the module Magento_Checkout module only Could you please suggest

Comment: Can you please clear your browser cache once ? and also please run all deployment command once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101014/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-nippu).

Comment: You can download this module and check.. https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/show-hide-proceed-to-checkout-minicart

Comment: @Kisan Savaliya I need your help regarding hiding to proceed to checkout at cart page bottom & need to add custom button as well. https://codeshare.io/GLppvN

Comment: Okay sure I'll help you there. Give me some time.

Comment: @krishan  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295718/magento2-hide-proceed-to-checkout-page-bottom-of-the-cart-page

Comment: Okay I'll check that.

Comment: [2022-11-21 09:18:22] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Vendor_Module/minicart/content" template requested by "minicart_content".
Please check just one error is occuring

Answer (score 1):

You can overrirde content.html by `requirejs-config.js` in your module.

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module_Name}/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html':
                'Vendor_ModuleName/template/minicart/content.html'
        }
    }
};
```

copy content.html from

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

paste to

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

Then, remove this below code from your module file :

And then remove this below code.

```
<button
   id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
   type="button"
   class="action primary checkout"
   data-action="close"
   data-bind="
   attr: {
   title: $t('Proceed to Checkout')
   },
   click: closeMinicart()
   "
   translate="'Proceed to Checkout'"
   />
```

Now, setup upgrade and flush cache.

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:f
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rohan it seems working. but let me check from my end and getback to you

Answer (score 0):

1) override

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html to your theme folder

and remove

```
                       <button
                    id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
                    type="button"
                    class="action primary checkout"
                    data-action="close"
                    data-bind="
                        attr: {
                            title: $t('Proceed to Checkout')
                        },
                        click: closeMinicart()
                    "
                    translate="'Proceed to Checkout'"
            />
```

block of code and check after running **php bin/magento se:up** command

or second simply add css for
**#top-cart-btn-checkout{
display:none}**

Comment: thanks for quick reply. but i would like to do it from my custom module can u advise?

Comment: No you have to change in your theme folder