# How to done a error message under shipping method in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

How to done a error message under shipping method in magento 2

like this..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Back-end, there is one option available to show error message. You just need to enable this setting there **"Show Method if Not Applicable"**.

[image]

[image]

You do not need to add any custom code. Just follow "Bank Transfer" or any other default Magento Shipping method modules and you can add that functionality for your custom shipping methods as well.

You need to check this file

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/shipping-method-item.html

There is Magento showing that error message.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if it helps. Thanks. :)

Comment: Sir, i want to know is any other way to show a dynamic custom message(except config message)  under  shipping method. i  want  to show my custom module message  https://prnt.sc/q6ew95

Comment: You can check this file for reference **vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php** and find **setErrorMessage** in that file so you will get idea how you can add custom error message there. Let me know if you need any help then..

Comment: You got any solution here ?

Comment: now i override a **vendor/module-checkout/View/frontend/web/template/shipping.html** and  tried to pass a error message via data bind, can you please tell me how to pass a data by js file

Comment: You mean you have static message or you want to get that message from any configurations ?

Comment: i want  to get a message from  backend https://prnt.sc/q6ew95

Comment: You can check this answer as a reference [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295579/magento-2-dont-want-to-show-proceed-to-checkout-button-based-on-custom-conditio)