# How to hide proceed to checkout button in mini-cart in magento 2

Tags: mini-cart, magento2.3.3, requirejs-config.js, mixins

I managed to hide the chekout button using a custom module. I followed this [threads](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295579/magento-2-dont-want-to-show-proceed-to-checkout-button-based-on-custom-conditio)
to achieve this. I can hide the checkout button in mini cart now.But i want to add some condition to show the Proceed to Checkout button. Where i want to pass the cart total value to **minicart.js** file in my custom module.

Below are the steps i tried

`(app/code/Ayakil/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml/etc/di.xml).`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" type="Ayakil\MinicartCustomization\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" />
</config>
```

My ***DefaultConfigProvider.php*** `( app/code/Ayakil/MinicartCustomization/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php )`

```
<?php
namespace Ayakil\MinicartCustomization\Model;

use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager;

class DefaultConfigProvider extends \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider
{
private $coreSession;
public function __construct(
    SessionManager $sessionManager
) {
    $this->coreSession = $sessionManager;    
}

public function getConfig()
{
    $output = parent::getConfig();
    if($this->coreSession->getVIErequestData()){
        $output['session_VIEUserData'] = true;
    }else{
        $output['session_VIEUserData'] = false;
    }

    return $output;
}
}
```

my ***minicart-mixin.js*** file like below.

```
define([
'uiComponent',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
'jquery',
'ko',
'underscore',
'sidebar',
'mage/translate',
'mage/dropdown'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, _) {
'use strict';

var mixin = {
    isButtonEnable: function () {
        /*You can add your condition here based on your requirements.*/
        console.log(window.checkoutConfig.session_VIEUserData);

        return false;
    }
};

return function (target) {
    return target.extend(mixin);
};
});
```

In my minicart-mixin.js file if i try to access like `console.log(window.checkoutConfig.session_VIEUserData);` i am getting an error.

> TypeError: window.CheckoutConfig is undefined

My question is how can i pass a variable to minicart-mixin.js and access the data?

Comment: Follow this solution if this will help you [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295908/magento-2-pass-php-session-variable-to-minicart-hide-proceed-to-checkout)

Comment: i followed this too, BUt still i am getting the same error.

Comment: You follow all the steps ?

Comment: yes, i just want to access the varibale in mixin.js?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya i followed both of your 2 answers and complete that task

Comment: Okay can you please let me know what condition you want to add there ? So I can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104084/discussion-between-mujahidh-and-kishan-savaliya).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add just your value and access in js file. Replace this below code in your function :

> app/code/Ayakil/MinicartCustomization/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="additional_provider" xsi:type="object">Ayakil\MinicartCustomization\Model\DefaultConfigProvider</item>
           </argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
</config>
```

and then, modify this below function code in your file :

```
public function getConfig()
{
    $output = [];
    if($this->coreSession->getVIErequestData()){
        $output['session_VIEUserData'] = true;
    }else{
        $output['session_VIEUserData'] = false;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "your value"? Are you referring to console.log(session_VIEUserData);

Comment: I mean remove $output = parent::getConfig(); and add $output = [];

Comment: still same issue

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: how can access this value in mixin.js?

Comment: same as like you did : console.log(window.checkoutConfig.session_VIEUserData);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **Cookie** value in condition then try to replace your `minicart-mixin.js` content with below code.

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'sidebar',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/dropdown',
    'jquery/jquery.cookie'
], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, _) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        isButtonEnable: function () {
            /*You can add your condition here based on your requirements.*/
            var check_cookie = $.cookie('foo');

            if(check_cookie == 'something'){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

Hope this will help you!